# SQL Subtract from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm subtracting values from diferent tables based on ID.

Its like an inventory where I've the tables for Itens In and Itens Out.

What I want to do is to substract the Itens In - Itens Out based on ID of the iten.

I manage to do that, but if an Iten only as an In movement, the query just shows an empty row, when it should show the In movement - Out moment that even if it doesnt exists should be considered as 0, showing in this case only the value of the IN movment.

Can someone help?

Each row in each table represents one item.

---

TABLE - in_used

id_item_____qnt
1            _________500
2            _________1000

TABLE - out_used

id_item_____qnt
1            _________200

OUTPUT EXPECTED

used_stock

id_item____qnt
1         ________300
2         ________1000 (there's no out movement so it should show only the IN one)

```sql
Select
    in_used.qnt - out_used.qnt As used_Stock
From
    in_used Inner Join
    out_used On in_used.id_item = out_used.id_item
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your existing query is also helpful.

Comment: Show table schemas, example data, current query, current output, and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id_item` is unique in `in_used` and there is at most 1 row in `out_used` then all you need is a `LEFT` join and `COALESCE()`:

```
select i.id_item, 
       i.qnt - coalesce(o.qnt, 0) used_Stock
from in_used i left join out_used o
on i.id_item = o.id_item
```

If there are more rows use also aggregation:

```
select i.id_item, 
       sum(i.qnt) - coalesce(sum(o.qnt), 0) used_Stock
from in_used i left join out_used o
on i.id_item = o.id_item
group by i.id_item
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
select item, sum(inc)
from ((select item, in_used as inc
       from items_in
      ) union all
      (select item, - out_used as inc
       from items_out
      )
     ) ii
group by item;
```

I'm not sure if each row in the two tables represents one item or if there is a counter.  If there is a counter, then that should be used instead of `1`/`-1`.

Comment: Not sure I understand your solution...

I've updated the question

Comment: @xela05 . . . I'm not sure what is difficult to understand about a `union all` and `group by`.  Note:  This works for all items, even those that are in only one table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one record per id you can use sum() and must use FULL JOIN if there a no records on both tables or otherwise you can use LEFT JOIN

```
Select
    id_item , coalesce(sum(in_used.qnt),0) - coalesce(sum(out_used.qnt),0) As used_Stock
From
    in_used FULL Join
    out_used On in_used.id_item = out_used.id_item
GROUP BY id_item
```

Comment: Solution you provide does not work...

The left join gets closer but shoes an empty row instead of the IN value

Comment: Sorry, coalesce was missing :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case we know that we have id_item in all cases for join results and none of them would be null:

```
SELECT I.id_item,
    SUM(I.qnt) - SUM(O.qnt) AS used_Stock
FROM in_used AS I
JOIN out_used AS O ON I.id_item = O.id_item
GROUP BY id_item
```

But for general result, you can try below query:

```
SELECT (CASE
        WHEN I.id_item IS NOT NULL THEN I.id_item
        ELSE O.id_item
    END) AS id_item,
    SUM(I.qnt) - SUM(O.qnt) AS used_Stock
FROM in_used AS I
JOIN out_used AS O ON I.id_item = O.id_item
GROUP BY id_item
```

Hope this works for you!